# harmonic functions on the complex plane that vanish in an open set vanish everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a harmonic $u$ on an domain $\Omega$ and suppose $u$ is zero in an open set $V$.  We want to show that $u$ vanishes on $\Omega$.

Proof:  Let $v$ be the harmonic conjugate of $u$ so that $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic.  Since $u$ vanishes on $V$ the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that $v$ also vanishes.  Hence $f=0$ on $V$ and by the identiy theorem $f$ mush vanish on all of $\Omega$.

I was wondering if there was a proof of this claim that only uses the fact that $u$ is harmonic without resorting to harmonic conjugates and the heavy machinery of complex analysis.

Comment: $u$ need not have a harmonic conjugate in all of $\Omega$, so even with the big rigs you have some work to do.

Comment: It will if we assume $\Omega$ has a smooth boundary right?

Comment: No, think about an annulus.

Comment: hmmm, what if we joined any point in $\Omega$ with one in $U$  and covered it with 
a finite number of open balls contained in the domain.  Then used the idea above inductively on each open set on the path

Comment: That's an idea worth exploring.

Comment: Ya I'm pretty sure it works because $u$ has a harmonic conjugate in each convex ball

Comment: This result is true for harmonic  functions in any dimension so doesn't  depend on the existence  of the harmonic  conjugate which  is specifically a plane thing; it follows easily from the fact that $u$ is real analytic which is true in any (finite) dimension; more generally a harmonic (real) function in an open domain cannot have a local extremum unless it is constant, so it always attains both max and min on boundaries